# why my firefox add-on cannot do Request

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

My addon is working fine without bugs, But If add the bellow code in my addon script  Main.js then my extension will not work at all.

Why?

What I should do ?

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var quijote = Request({
  url: "http://www.latin1files.org/",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    console.log(response.text);
  }
});

quijote.get();
```

**Addon:**

https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/_files/478037/proxylist-initial.rev19-fx.xpi

**So the addon is not working if I want to use Request or Timer. How to resolve this ?**

I think the problem is in settings files, maybe in bootstrap.js or harness-options.json, or somewhere where it must be initialized, but i don't know much about firefox addon sdk. I know that above code must work, but i need to include or to declare something that will allow me to use Request.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? The whole extension stops working or `onComplete` isn't being executed? If it's the latter, it could be because `http://www.latin1files.org` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @willlma whole extension stops working

Comment: The code looks reasonable enough, so the real issue is likely with the rest of the code you didn't post or more precisely with the interaction of the two. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @nmaier I think the problem is in settings files, maybe in bootstrap.js, or somewhere where it must be initialized, but i don't know much about firefox addon sdk. I know that above code must work, but i need to include or to declare something that will allow me to use Request.

Comment: or harness-options.json

Comment: You must be getting an error somewhere. Is there nothing in the console? Do you use other modules? Can you generate an xpi file properly?

Comment: @willlma in the browser webpage console is nothing about addon. I use other modules, my extension work good , but if I want to use Request then extension not work, because i think it is not configured, I think. And I'm not using sdk tools, I just zip the files and save as xpi, so i Edit the files with Notepad directly.

Comment: @willlma please check my question again I have added some changed and add the link of extension to download, so you can check better. I cannot understand how to make it to work, the documentation is not so good.

Comment: @nmaier please check my question again I have added some changed and add the link of extension to download, so you can check better. I cannot understand how to make it to work, the documentation is not so good.

Comment: I've never seen someone try to combine a bootstrapped add-on and an sdk add-on like this, but assuming it works somehow, I would guess that your problem is that the request.js module is missing. Try downloading the latest version of the SDK and somehow incorporating it into your file structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That must be declared in harness-options.json

Answer (score 0):

There is no request.js file in your /resources/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/ folder. As you can see in the comments to [the announcement of SDK 1.15](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2013/12/12/announcing-add-on-sdk-1-15/), bundling the SDK modules with the extension is no longer necessary (since FF21).

Comment: but even if i add the request.js in the that folder, it will not work.

Comment: Are you trying to make a pure addon-sdk extension? Did you write bootstrap.js? The file structure is completely different from what I've seen since I started making extensions. If you're just trying to make a normal add-on sdk extension, then download and install the [newest sdk](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/03/27/announcing-add-on-sdk-1-16/), create a new extension with `cfx init`, and replace the generated `main.js` file with your own.